# Saltstack not respecting watch/require

Tags: nginx, salt-stack

I am trying to deploy nginx using Saltstack.  I am not using the nginx formula.  Here is what I have:

```
nginx:
  pkg.installed
  service.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/com.example.static
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/com.example.static
      - method: reload
```

I also have an entry defined for `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/com.example.static`.  It is working correctly -- the file is getting copied to the right location.

The problem is that nginx isn't getting reloaded when when Saltstack puts the configuration file on the system.  I need to run `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` before the server will respond to requests for `static.example.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add a `reload` directive to `service.running`

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html

*"By default if a service is triggered to refresh due to a watch statement the service is by default restarted. If the desired behavior is to reload the service, then set the reload value to True."*

```
nginx:
  ...
  service.running:
    ...
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/com.example.static
```

Also see github ticket [#1122](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/1122)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if the problem is that the file in `sites-enabled` is a symlink, rather than a regular file

Comment: run state.apply with "--out=json" and you will see why. watch is looking at 'changes' in the returned json from the watched state.